# A problem about proving some spaces are not conformally equivalent

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the unit disk $D$,the complex plane $C$ and extended complex plane $C^{\ast}$.Show that no two of them are conformally equivalence.

From Liouville theorem,it's easy to see that disk is not conformally equivalent with plane and extended plane. I don't know how to prove that plane and extended plane can't be conformally equivalent.

Comment: The extended plane is compact, so they are not even homeomorphic